# Unable to call forEach function from an Array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class with an array of object.

```
export interface Filter {
  sf?:Array<{key:string,value:string}>;
}
```

I try to use forEach function to loop and log each object value inside the array.

```
f : Filter = {sf:[{key:'a',value:'b'},{key:'c',value:'d'}]}; 

f.sf.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.key);
});
```

However error appears inside the mongo db server.

```
[error] f.sf.forEach is not a function 0
node                           | TypeError: f.sf.forEach is not a function
```

how can I fix this error so the forEach works? thank you.

Comment: Could it be that `f.sf` is `undefined` as permitted by the Filter interface definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by your `Filter` interface, `sf` is optional.

Optional values will default to `undefined` (unless otherwise stated). You can check if a variable is not defined in many ways:

```js
const myVariable = undefined
const myOtherVar = null

// double "=", not always a great way to test the value
console.log("myVariable, ==", myVariable == undefined)
console.log("myVariable, ===", myVariable === undefined)

console.log("myOtherVar ==", myOtherVar == undefined
console.log("myOtherVar ===", myOtherVar === undefined
```

**Note how `undefined == null` is `true` but `undefined === null` is `false`**

You either need to make it non-optional like so:

```js
export interface Filter {
  sf:Array<{key:string,value:string}>;
}
```

Another way of writing this is:

```js
type SF = {
  key:string,
  value:string
}

interface Filter {
  sf: SF[];
}
```

Or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this:

```js
f.sf?.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.key);
});
```

Comment: After trying the optional chaining, it returns error `TypeError: _a.forEach is not a function`...

Comment: Hi I also added a `if(f.sf!=null)` statement outside the forEach function, since my post's edit function is bug, I want to tell you this addition info here. Hope it is useful.

Comment: I also checked the object with function Array.isArray(f.sf), seems like it is false...

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn Optional objects will default to `undefined`, not necessarily `null`. `null` and undefined can be tricky, because: `undefined != null // false` BUT `undefined !== null // true`. Also if you got `_a.forEach is not a function` then you have the same optional issue for the variable `a` (Provided a is an optional array too)

Comment: Found the problem, its outside of this topic scope. Turns out angular `form.value` do not return array, its an object. Have to map it back into an array.